# Vagrantfile for configuring vm in vagrant having forward_port 80, 8080 is throwing error

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have the following in my Vagrantfile.

```
config.vm.forward_port 80, 8080
```

And when I do Vagrant up, I get this error. My intent is port mapping from guest to host.

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: forward_port
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member variable for the `config` object in that block should be `forwarded_port`, with symbol type arguments of `guest` and `host`, and a member method of `network`, so your line should appear like:

```
config.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 80, host: 8080
```